# How was the hash collision issue in ASP.NET fixed (MS11-100)?

Tags: asp.net, .net, denial-of-service, hash-collision, ms11-100

[As reported by Slashdot](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/11/12/29/1352219), MS issued [an update to ASP.NET to fix the hash collision attack](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms11-100) today. (Listed as "Collisions in HashTable May Cause DoS Vulnerability - CVE-2011-3414" on the linked Technet page.)

The problem is that the POST data are converted into a hash table that uses a known hashing algorithm. And if an attacker uses this by crafting a request that contains lots of collisions, he can easily cause a Denial of Service.

Does anyone know how exactly does that update fix the issue?

Comment: I would expect that they just used a better hash algorithm, but I'm not sure and haven't seen any details anywhere.

Comment: Could also be they introduced some random parameter into the algorithm.

Comment: this might help you ....<http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/12/28/asp-net-security-update-shipping-thursday-dec-29th.aspx>

Comment: @salman That page does not describe how the issue was fixed, only that a patch is available.

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed as a question that is not constructive. The question could be perfectly answered using facts and references. Maybe all relevant facts are not yet publically known, but that isn't a reason to close the question, or is it?

Comment: Here is a proposed solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696718/validate-request-before-application-beginrequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update is not a complete fix, but rather a workaround. It limits the number of POST parameters accepted.

Comment: How did you find that out? Do you have some source?

Comment: Guys that presented this vulnerability gave this information.

Comment: @Peri and where did they do that?

Comment: Here are the slides http://events.ccc.de/congress/2011/Fahrplan/events/4680.en.html and here is the video http://mirror.fem-net.de/CCC/28C3/mp4-h264-HQ/28c3-4680-en-effective_dos_attacks_against_web_application_platforms_h264.mp4

Comment: The will be a update, but for now we can use the solution proposed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696718/validate-request-before-application-beginrequest

Comment: Better to use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8684879/4830) if you need to workaround the limitation: `<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />` to your appSettings in web.config.