# Microsoft security bulletin MS11-100 breaking our site

Tags: asp.net, ms11-100

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET, MS11-100, and POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684049/asp-net-ms11-100-and-post)

After applying the updates from the Microsoft security bulletin MS11-100 certain forms on our site stopped working.  The exception says "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." It also says "[HttpException (0x80004005): The URL-encoded form data is not valid.]"  We haven't changed any code??

Comment: This will save you some searching:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684049/asp-net-ms11-100-how-can-i-change-the-limit-on-the-maximum-number-of-posted-for

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that this patch accomplishes is that it limits the number of name/value pairs in submitted form data to 500. I'm not sure *what* happens, frankly, if you have a valid form which exceeds this; but in your case, the first thing I'd check would be whether or not those forms exceeded this limit.