# The URL-encoded form data is not valid - Solution not working in some case

Tags: asp.net

This is in reference to the solution posted here:

[The URL-encoded form data is not valid Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8684879/1004522)

I have added this line in my web.config in appSettings section:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="3000" />
```

But the issue persists. Please help. Interestingly, this issue is not reproducing on my local host but on the production server, it is occuring.

Comment: I think that is bad design ! how many keys do you have ? or what kind of data do you send ? maybe you do not encode them ? Please show the url that have the issue here.

Comment: Well its a licensed product so I can not share the url. However, I have around 38 keys in appSettings section. The page which is causing this issue has a grid with hundreds of records within an update panel.

Comment: Please add a sample URL that it is throwing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible problems in your case.

1. You do not UrlEncode every value on your keys.
2. Some keys contains invalid URL characters.

check this two on your `secret url string` to locate the issue.