# Set aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In a bit of admin functionality for a particular site, I'm doing a particularly horrific post that necessitates a *large* amount of data to be posted. [In order to make that happen, I had to add the Web.config appSetting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832470/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-error-during-pos):

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />
```

However, I only want this large post to be possible under a particular set of circumstances. Is there any way to programmatically set this value?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325558/asp-net-specifying-maxhttpcollectionkeys-for-a-specific-page-is-this-possible

Comment: Can you combine the data into an JSON object, post that, and deserialize it on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible, per this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10753846/570190

"You cannot override this because the reading of the setting and the default value is done inside an internal class."

Answer (score 1):

You could make the setting specific to a location by placing the appSetting under a location tag in your web.config.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx

Comment: I've done that and verified that the config setting propagates through to the running code (by checking the config value in a breakpoint), but I get the same model binding error as if the setting weren't there at all. Is it possible that MVC for some reason doesn't honor this setting under a `location`?

Comment: @eouw0o83hf I'm having the same issue in a regular ASP.NET app I'm supporting. Moving it under `<location>` causes the `InvalidOperationException` to happen all over again.

Answer (score 0):

You could isolate the form in a separate website in a virtual folder, with its own web.config. Of course if you need shared state then this can get quite complex (but not impossible). So perhaps by looking at it like a separate 'web service' that just happens to be able to handle 2000 items might solve the issue.