# ASP.NET Table Causes 500 Error after PostBack Occurs

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Good day! I've spent quite a few hours trying to figure this one out and now I need some help.

I have an ASP.NET AjaxToolKit `TabContainer` which has four `TabPanel` children. Each of these children has it's own `UpdatePanel` so I can run the logic in each panel without reloading everything (AJAX).

Here's my problem:

In my SECOND`TabPanel` I have some markup that looks like this:

```
<div id="ProgramMilestonesDiv" style="margin-left: 6px;">
    <asp:Table ID="ProgramMilestonesTable" runat="server" Visible="true">
    </asp:Table>
</div>
```

In my `Page_Init` routine I dynamically add row/cells/labels/texboxes to the control.

When I do a postback in the SECOND `TabPanel`, any postbacks in the FIRST `TabPanel` now cause a 500 error to be returned from the server. If I never do a postback in the SECOND, the FIRST postback runs fine. This is even if I don't put any values in the dynamically created controls for the table (i.e., I'm not putting any invalid characters in there to trip the page validation).

If I remove the dynamic creation of the textboxes it works, but I'm stumped as to why because they are blank AND I've made sure all the control IDs are unique. I even have a bunch of other dynamically created textboxes on the page, using the same code-behind method for doing so, and they work fine (they are in tables in `Accordion` controls).

Any suggestions on what might be going wrong? Any suggestions on debugging it to see the specific reason it is failing?

My code-behind for creating the textboxes looks like this:

```
 public static void AddVariableCostRowToTable(Table TargetTable, string CostArea, string CostType, Extender Extender)
    {
        string[] quarters = { "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12" };

        TableRow row = new TableRow(); // New row we'll add to table.

        // First cell is just the name of the cost.
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Width = new Unit(175);
        label.Text = CostType.Replace('_', ' ') + ":";
        cell.Controls.Add(label);
        row.Controls.Add(cell);

        // Create all the textboxes for the individual quarters.
        foreach (string q in quarters)
        {
            row.Controls.Add(CreateNewCellWithTextBox(CostArea, CostType, q, Extender));
        }

        TargetTable.Controls.Add(row); // Add the row to the table.
    }

 public static TableCell CreateNewCellWithTextBox(string CostArea, string CostType, string Quarter, Extender Extender)
    {
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();

        textbox.ID = CostArea + CostType + Quarter; // string
        textbox.Width = new Unit(65); // Pixels wide.
        textbox.Text = "";
        if (Extender == Extender.MASKED_EDIT_EXTENDER) textbox.Text = "0"; // Only initialize to 0 if textbox is for money.
        textbox.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "right");
        textbox.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;

        cell.Controls.Add(textbox);

        if (Extender == Extender.MASKED_EDIT_EXTENDER) // If calling routine wanted a $$$ filter on the textbox.
        {
            // Add an ajaxtoolkit extender so we can enforce currency formatting.
            MaskedEditExtender extender = new MaskedEditExtender();
            extender.ID = "MaskedEditExtender" + textbox.ID;
            extender.TargetControlID = textbox.ID;
            extender.Mask = "999999";
            extender.OnFocusCssClass = "MaskedEditFocus";
            extender.MaskType = MaskedEditType.Number;
            extender.InputDirection = MaskedEditInputDirection.RightToLeft;
            extender.AcceptNegative = MaskedEditShowSymbol.Left;
            extender.DisplayMoney = MaskedEditShowSymbol.Left;

            cell.Controls.Add(extender);
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I was exceeding the number of controls allowed in a single postback.

You can read about it here:

[ASP.NET MS11-100: how can I change the limit on the maximum number of posted form values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684049/asp-net-ms11-100-how-can-i-change-the-limit-on-the-maximum-number-of-posted-for)

I used this web.config setting to increase it:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />
</appSettings>
```

Whether I should be using that many controls is an entirely different question. :)

I figured this out by removing other content on my page. When I did, it started to work again.

This nearly drove me to the brink of insanity. Hooray!