# Internal server 500 error with 958 records (not maxRequestLength issue)

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have a System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView control.  This is running in an ASP.Net SharePoint Web Part application using .Net 3.5.

On form submit, if this grid has 957 rows, it works fine.  If it has 958 rows, it fails.  I'm confident that this is not a maxRequestLength overflow because I have changed that in web.config, and I've also loaded 957 records of large size, and then 958 records of a smaller size and the same behavior occurs.  It's not any one record either because I load more records than that and then randomly eliminate them before returning the view to the client (which is how I found the magic number of 958).

It's never random; 957 records will always submit no matter what the total size and despite any delays while debugging (no timeout occurs).  958 will always fail.  The actual server error returned is:

Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

I am beyond stumped. Has anyone run into something like this before or have any ideas?

Comment: did you used UpdatePanel ?

Comment: Yes, UpdatePanel is the root element in the ASP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be 1000 key value pairs in the submitted data.  That's why the number of records broke at 958 (there were 43 other key value pairs in the form submission).

ASP.Net has a limit of 1000 records.  The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684049/asp-net-ms11-100-how-can-i-change-the-limit-on-the-maximum-number-of-posted-for) completely explains this.