# Validate request before Application_BeginRequest?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, httpwebrequest, httpmodule

I trying to perform aditional validation before application start reading the input of the request, to end suspicious request, based on headers and form data or something like that.

Is there it possible?

**[Update]**

I'm focusing in prevent a zero day vunerability that occurs before BeginRequest and ins't catch by ASP .net validation.

If I could control the creation of the HttpWebRequest object I could detect this attack.

**[Solution]**

It can be solved using a native module.

Information about a creating a native module can be found here (using C++):
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/169/develop-a-native-cc-module-for-iis/

The zero day vulnerability I was talking is described in this blog post:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2011/12/27/more-information-about-the-december-2011-asp-net-vulnerability.aspx

I made a fix for it (is a pre release, not suitable for production) and can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/ginx/HashCollisionDetector

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: It looks like your solution is still using the BeginRequest event, right, just from native code instead of managed?

Comment: I using it, but the problem I was addressing occurred in ASP.net handler, with caused a DoS in all servers.

The native handler, I get the raw request, so, the problem aren't happened there yet.

Microsoft already fixed the bug, so it not happens anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved using a native module.

Native module are executed before any ASP .net validation.

Information about a creating a native module can be found here (using C++): http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/169/develop-a-native-cc-module-for-iis/

Answer (score 2):

`BeginRequest` is the first event in the IIS request-processing pipeline.

The only pre-request actions that happen before that event are the creation of instances the `HttpContext`, `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` classes.

It's also the case that the `BeginRequest` event in some registered `HttpModules` (including Global.asax) will run before others. However, ASP.NET makes no guarantees with regard to ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask HttpApplication to do this for you by setting pages [validateRequest="true"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.validaterequest.aspx) in your web.config.

Otherwise, you can attempt to replace some of the standard modules in the IIS pipeline (not recommended unless you have a lot of time on your hands).

Here are some very good resources:

[ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)

[IIS 7 Modules Overview](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/121/iis-modules-overview/)

[Customizing IIS 7.0 Roles and Modules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627313.aspx)

Comment: Any ideas how I can replace these standard modules?
Is exactly its I'm trying. Saddly, validareRequest is not perfect and I'm trying to fix a zero day vunerability.

Comment: I don't have any experience with this myself, but have you seen this MS KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957508 ? It might save you a ton of time.

Comment: There is also some good info in this link: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/543/administration-pack/